# Add the UNIX layer to your VxWorks Source Build project

Tags: unix, vxworks, wind-river-workbench

I'm trying to use UNIX commands in my Vxworks project. I read online that I can add an UNIX layer to my project, but there is no information on how to do that.

```
      How can I Add the UNIX layer to my VxWorks Source Build project.
```

Comment: Where did your read it, please cite the source. Which commands are you trying to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add UNIX Layer like:

```
$cd $VSB_DIR    
$vxprj vsb add UTILS_UNIX
```

But it will not bring in Unix tools inside VxWorks Environment, rather it will provide you enough functionalities so you can build some of the Unix libraries/tools(i.e. https://github.com/Wind-River/vxworks7-layer-for-bzip2) inside VxWorks.